# How much does a hard drive weigh?

Tags: hard-drive

What is the average weight of a SATA hard drive for desktops of 3.5" form factor. I think they make up for most of the weight inside the cabinet. Is it usually over 2.2 pounds (1 Kg)??

Comment: depends totally on the number of bits you have turned from 0 to 1 :)

Comment: Having a quick browse around, the heftiest 3.5" drive I can see is an IronWolf 8TB drive at 780g / 1.72lb (https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/ironwolf-12tbDS1904-9-1707US-en_US.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

[This Samsung drive](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/productmodel.do?type=94&subtype=98&model_cd=507) is pretty common these days.  Can't imagine they vary enormously...

625g, according to the mfr web site.

Answer (score 1):

Over 1 kg? Probably not much more than 0.5 kg.